# Change frame of cancel button in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, frame, uisearchbar

I have the following code to change the appearance of the UISearchBar in my application and it can be seen in the image below also:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [[searchBar subviews] count]; i++){
    UIView *subView = [[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:i];
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [subView class]] isEqualToString:@"UINavigationButton"]){
        UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton *)subView;

        CGRect buttonFrame = cancelButton.frame;
        buttonFrame.size.height = 52;
        [cancelButton setFrame:buttonFrame];

        [cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to change the height of the button contained in the UISearchBar with no luck. I do get reference to the button as I can change the text and the background Image is changed just not the height of the frame. I would just like the height of the button to be the same as the search box at 52px.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have found a really hacky solution, but it's not very elegant of adding a UIButton as the subview of the Cancel Button. It does the job but as I say it's not very nice.

Comment: is buttontype custom?

Comment: No it's a standard UIButton within the subviews of the UISearchBar. Just with a background set for each ControlState.

Comment: maybe subclass uisearchbar and override -addSubView method and setting the frame there?

Comment: changing the frame in `-addSubView` has no effect. My guess is that theres something inside Apple's `-layoutSubViews` with a hardcoded button size. You can override `-layoutSubViews` but it results in a bit of a dirty animation

Answer (score 4):

Actually you could use method below to access the cancel Button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

So I override `-layoutSubViews` with this, but theres 2 issues I have

I hate iterating through the views to find the matching view, and it messes up the animation a little bit

```
- (UIButton *)cancelButton {
    for (UIView *v in self.subviews) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            NSString *caption = [[((UIButton *)v) titleLabel] text];
            if ([caption isEqualToString:@"Cancel"] )
                return (UIButton *)v;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)cancelButtonIsShowing {
    return ([self cancelButton] != nil);
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if ([self cancelButtonIsShowing]) {
        UIButton *cancelButton = [self cancelButton];

        UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cancel_BTN"];
        CGRect f = CGRectMake(267, 5, i.size.width, i.size.height);
        cancelButton.frame = f;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a far more complex way to work around the glitch in the animation. If you need it, let me know